# How to know the sideMenu visibility state

Tags: react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I have a topBar with a button that toggles the Side Menu.

I have registered a navigationButtonPressed action as below

```
navigationButtonPressed({ buttonId }) {
    switch (buttonId) {
      case 'sideMenuButtonId':
        Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
          sideMenu: {
            left: {
              visible: true
            }
          }
        });
        break
      default:
        break
    }
  }
```

But in this case, the button only makes the sideMenu visible, and Im trying to use it so it toggles the menu open and closed.
So i replaced the above with a variable approach seen below..

```
var sideMenuVisible = false

navigationButtonPressed({ buttonId }) {
    switch (buttonId) {
      case 'sideMenuButtonId':
        sideMenuVisible = !sideMenuVisible
        Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
          sideMenu: {
            left: {
              visible: sideMenuVisible
            }
          }
        });
        break
      default:
        break
    }
  }
```

Which works fine if the user only uses the button to open and closed the sideMenu, but the user can also open/close the menu by swiping to open the menu as well as tapping out the menu to close it.

Is there a way to check the visibility of the `sideMenu` so I can properly use an action to open/close the menu on command?

Answer (score 0):

It can done much more simple. 
Think you should create it as a state, because the component have to know, it should be rerendered, when the state change.
So something like

```
state = { isOpen: false };

toggleSidebar = () => {
  this.setState({ isOpen: !isOpen })
}
```

And now, you should call the toggleSidebar function when you click the button

Comment: thanks jonask. Yeah that probably is a better approach to handle the button click, but the slightly bigger problem effectively knowing the visibility of the sideMenu since it can be closed/open in multiple ways.
So using a variable to manage the `isOpen` state is reliable half the time, when the user uses the button/action, and not using slide or swipe gestures (for instance)

Comment: But it still sounds like you should change it to be a state. You won't see any effect changing a variable, because your component won't rerender

Comment: @Simon Can you share me code to navigate between screen from drawer? I'm having problem handling swipe gestures. Thanks.